# URLにあるxsdなどのxmlを効率的に参照したい

Tags: xml

Servletのweb.xmlの構造(スキーマ)を確認したいので、
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd
URLから効率的に参照できるビューワーなどはありますか？
VSCodeやAtomのプラグインや、他にツールなどがあったら教えてください。

例えば、xsdのxsd:includeなら、
自動でインクルードされて表示されるか、クリックしたらそのxmlに遷移すればよいです

Answer (score 0, accepted):

外していたらすみません．XMLエディタのoXygenなら`File` - `Open URL`メニューから簡単にXSDを開けます．以下 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd を開いた画面ショットです．

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: とても使いやすそうですが有料なのがネックですね。本格的に業務で必要になるなら購入を検討したいです。